# CSV出力時の入力フォームの値の取得方法

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptからCSV出力を行いたいのですが、作業中にエラーが出てしまいました。
（下記に記載）

私では力不足なので皆様にお力添えいただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

**参考にしたサイト**
[【JavaScript】CSVのダウンロード機能を実装する！Excelの日本語文字化け対応](https://into-the-program.com/javascript-download-csv/)
[jQueryで複数のinputからそれぞれのvalueを取得する。](https://qiita.com/Yuji-207/items/cf1da4ba3eb35cb308f8)

**エラー内容**

```
index.js:97 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.downloadCSV (index.js:97)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**JavaScript**

```
function downloadCSV() {
  //ダウンロードするCSVファイル名を指定する
  const filename = "download.csv";
  //CSVデータ
  const inputs = $('.input').each(function(index, element){
    return element.value;
});
  
  //BOMを付与する（Excelでの文字化け対策）
  const bom = new Uint8Array([0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf]);
  //Blobでデータを作成する
//エラー
  const blob = new Blob([bom, data], { type: "text/csv" });

  //IE10/11用
  //download属性が機能しないためmsSaveBlobを使用する
  if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

      //その他ブラウザ
  } else {
      //BlobからURLを作成する
      const url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      //ダウンロード用にリンクを作成する
      const download = document.createElement("a");
      //リンク先に上記で生成したURLを指定する
      download.href = url;
      //download属性にファイル名を指定する
      download.download = filename;
      //作成したリンクをクリックしてダウンロードを実行する
      download.click();
      //createObjectURLで作成したURLを開放する
      (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
}

//ボタンを取得する
const download = document.getElementById("download");
//ボタンがクリックされたら「downloadCSV」を実行する
download.addEventListener("click", downloadCSV, false);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>


  <body><br><br><br><br>


<div id="container"></div>
<table align="center">

        <tr><td>名前<br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td>email<br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br></td></tr>
        <tr><td>出力先<br></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="messege" id="messege"><br><br></td></tr>

        <input type="button" id="download" value="CSV出力">
      
      </table>
      </form>


      <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: エラーの文字通り「dataという変数がない」なのでdataを用意すればよいと見受けられますが、具体的に何がわからないですか？

Comment: `const blob = new Blob([bom, data], { type: "text/csv" });` ここの`data`は何処から？

Comment: keitaro_soさん、Ricky Moさん　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
 const data = "テスト, テスト, テスト\nテスト, テスト, テスト";　→　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　const date = $('.input').each(function(index, element){
    return element.value;
});　　　元々上記のようにあったのを今回の仕様通りに複数に変数を入れたくて直したのですがたぶんそこが違うといっているのかなと思います。。なので複数あった場合の変数の入れ方を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: qiitaの参考にしているサイトを見ると参考サイトにはある`.get()`が質問のソースコードにはなくなっていますけど、何か意図がありますか？

Comment: ちなみに[jQueryのセレクタ](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)の仕様は把握されていますでしょうか？

Comment: keitaro_so さん 普通に忘れていました、ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: keitaro_soさん　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　プログラミング、jQueryを使うのが初めてなので理解できていないところも多いと思います。いただいたサイトを見てみましたが、理解が追い付いてないように感じます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> index.js:97 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at HTMLInputElement.downloadCSV (index.js:97)

ここは `data` ではなく `inputs` ではないでしょうか。

```js
  //エラー
  const blob = new Blob([bom, inputs], { type: "text/csv" });
```

また、入力された文字列を CSV 形式にするので `each` ではなく `map` を使う方がよいかと思います。

```js
  //CSVデータ
  const inputs = $('input[type=text]').map((_, element) => {
    return element.value;
  }).get().join(',');
```

**追記**

> 入力フォームの内容ではなく謎の文字がでてしまいました。。

こちらの環境は以下の通りですが、文字化けは起きていません。

- Windows 10 Home 20H2 19042.868
- Google Chrome 95.0.4638.54
- Excel 2016 MSO(version 2019 build 16.0.14430.20154)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。いただいたソースを書いてみたところCSV出力することができました。ですが入力フォームの内容ではなく謎の文字がでてしまいました。。写真を追加したのでみていただきたいです。

Comment: どうも Shift-JIS として読み込まれている様に見えます。Excel の場合、BOM を付加しておくと UTF-8 エンコーディングで読んでくれると様々な記事に書かれていますね。。。例えば、Excel で開くのではなく、ファイルにダウンロードした場合は文字化けが発生しますでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルにダウンロードするやり方がわからなく、、教えていただきたいです。。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
  //BOMを付与する（Excelでの文字化け対策）
  const bom = new Uint8Array([0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf]);
  //Blobでデータを作成する
  const blob = new Blob([bom, inputs], { type: "text/csv" });　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　なるべくエクセルでやれるならやりたいと思っているのですが、文字化け適用のために書いているのに、上記は適用されていないのですよね、、

Comment: ブラウザ上で「CSV出力」のボタンをクリックすると Excel で開くかファイルに保存するかを選ぶ様なダイアログボックスが表示されるかと思うのですが、出ませんか？ ブラウザは何をお使いでしょうか？(こちらは FireFox を使用しています)

Comment: chromeを使用しています。出るのは「開く」「この種類のファイルは常に開く」「フォルダは開く」「キャンセル」が出てきます。

Comment: それでは「フォルダを開く」を選択して、`download.txt` をメモ帳で開いて内容を確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。download.csv → download.txt に名前を変更してメモ帳で見ましたが、何も表示されていませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。。。こちらは今の所 Linux 環境で試しているので Windows を用意して確認してみますね(少し時間が掛かりそうです)。

Comment: すみません、お手数おかけします。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 追記しましたが、こちらでは文字化けは発生しませんね。。。

Comment: 本当ですね、、調べてくださりありがとうございます。こちらでも考えてみます。

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input">　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　とクラスを付けたらいけるようになりました。たくさん時間を使ってくださりありがとうございました。